# How can I make this PHP <td> Conditional?

Tags: php, operators

I am trying to get this PHP table cell to write a color depending on a condition but I am missing something that is causing a Syntax error?

**Here is the code:**

```
$table = '<table>
<tr>
 <th> Qty </th>
 <th> Length </th>
 <th> Description </th>
 <th> Color </th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>'.$gauge. ' &nbsp; ' .$panel.  '</td>'
 if ($sscolor == "None")
   {
         '<td>' .$color. '</td>';    
   }
       else
   {
         '<td>' .$sscolor. '</td>';
   }
   '</td>
</tr> ';
```

Comment: The problem is pretty obvious, but if you get errors then you should tell us what they are.

Comment: if its easy than just provide a solution.

Comment: Wow, you clearly appreciate other people's time, huh.

Comment: I absolutely appreciate the people who took the time to give me constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can't put an if/else conditional inside a string. You can use a ternary though.

```
 $str = 'text'.($sscolor == 'None' ? $color : $sscolor).' more text'; // etc
```

Otherwise you'll need to end the string before the if, then concatenate more onto it using `.=`

Answer (score 0):

You can't place a IF condition in a variable after you write some string to it
I suggest this is how you do it

```
if ($sscolor == "None")
   {
         $extra_string = '<td>' .$color. '</td>';    
   }
       else
   {
        $extra_string = '<td>' .$sscolor. '</td>';
   }
$table = '<table>
<tr>
 <th> Qty </th>
 <th> Length </th>
 <th> Description </th>
 <th> Color </th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>'.$gauge. ' &nbsp; ' .$panel.  '</td>' . $extra_string . '
</tr> ';
```

Comment: I am trying this in my code which has taken away any syntax errors, however when I run the code it still will not print the color?

Comment: Are $color and $sscolor set? Are you echoing out the table?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to close the string concatenation with a semicolon, `;`, before the `if` statement. If you do not then you will get a syntax error:

```
<td>'.$gauge. ' &nbsp; ' .$panel.  '</td>' <-- Semicolon here
if ($sscolor == "None")                      <-- Syntax error, unexpected if token
```

A good way to avoid stuff like this is to use a heredoc string:

```
// Figure out the color before going into the string
if ($sscolor === 'None') {
  $color = $sscolor;
}
// heredoc string, with string interpolation
$table = <<< HTML
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Length</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>{$gauge} &nbsp; {$panel}</td>
      <td>{$color}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
HTML;
```

Learn more about [strings](http://php.net/string).

Also, even the best PHP programmers have to deal with errors. It is a part of learning PHP. So, you should get in the habit of googling error messages; they are easy to find, and you will be able to help yourself and learn at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You need to concatenate the lines withint the if statement.

```
<td>'.$gauge. ' &nbsp; ' .$panel.  '</td>';
 if ($sscolor == "None") {
    $table .= '<td>' .$color. '</td>';    
 } else {
     $table .= '<td>' .$sscolor. '</td>';
 }
$table .= '</td>';
```

Comment: You cannot concatenate a string directly to an if/else conditional.